# How to clear validation errors and submit at once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with jquery validation. When I enter a value with error, it show the error and adds the border css.

Then I enter a valid value and hit the submit button, but instead of submitting directly, first it erases the error message and waits for me to hit the submit button again.

How can I manage to do clear errors and submit at once?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?  Surely, you cannot expect us to figure out where you made this mistake without seeing what you've done to create this condition?  Yes, you've made a mistake; by default the Validate plugin does not do what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for your form; If you need more help send us your codes.

```
$(function () {
            $("#registerForm").validate({
                errorElement: "span",
                errorClass: "help-block",
                validClass: "has-success",
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: "Wrong Mail!",
                },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
                {
                    $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
                {
                    $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success");
                }
            });
        });
```